# Magento Gift Wrapping with Gift Message

Tags: magento-1.9

Have searched and searched but haven’t yet found an answer to this.

In Config > sales > Gift options I have enabled ‘Allow Gift Messages for Order Items’. My question is, can I add a charge for this? Per item?

If so, how would I go about doing this?

Many thanks in advance!

Sorry everyone, but I’m going to give this a bump - surely there must be a way to add a charge to the gift message if one has been entered?

The problem I’m having is that my client charges £3 per item gift wrapped, not one charge per gift wrap, and so I’m even struggling to find a module to achieve this.

But it seems silly to have an additional module anyway if the gift options are already available within Magento - I just need to add a charge per message entered.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not included in the standard Magento CE. You should have a look in the marketplace or create your own module, for example an observer that adds a fee to the grand total when there is a message.